# Install packages from Ubuntu Trusty on Focal

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-20.04, apt

Basically I have a legacy piece of software that I cannot manage to upgrade the libraries. Because of that I need specifically the libboost-dev 1.54, which is available on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty while using Ubuntu 20.04 Focal.

Can I somehow install it manually? I am trying to find a way to correctly add the old repositories which contains the old version of libboost to the source list of my Ubuntu Focal, but not working at all.

Anything is welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although it's generally not recommended to run older libraries from previous Ubuntu releases on newer releases due to compatibility issues and security updates.

If it is a must , you can try to manually download and install the package; manually download the .deb package for libboost-dev version 1.54 from the Ubuntu Trusty archives, then use dpkg command to install it - this might be challenging due to dependency issues  or  as an alternative you can download  the source from https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_54_0.html and compile from source;  this link https://github.com/boostorg/wiki/wiki/Getting-Started%3A-Overview there is a section that explains Building and installing the Boost libraries from source.

I hope this helps.